# Before Save flow on User fails to execute; works fine from UX

Tags: rest-api, before-save-flow

A simple Before Save flow on user that coerces the `User.FederationId` from the `User.Email` address given certain conditions.

- When I enter a new user via the UX, the flow runs fine and the `FederationId` is coerced
- When I create a new user via a POST API, using the same user data, the Flow does not coerce the `FederationId` from the email

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is not a permissions issue. The running user is the same in both UX and REST API use case

What is different though is how the flow's entry condition is evaluated

```
UserType = Standard
```

- When submitting from the UX, `UserType` is set by SFDC and is non-null
- When submitted from the API (or, for that matter, as presented to a trigger), `UserType` is null.  You can see in the [User Object definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) that is a derived field

As this [Knowledge Article states](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318227&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1), this is working-as-designed.

The Flow entry condition needs to be removed and replaced with a

- GET Record element that does: `SELECT Id, UserType from Profile where Id = {!$Record.ProfileId}` and
- Decision block that routes logic based on query result

*This is one of those relatively rare cases where testing a record-triggered flow from the UX can lead to a false sense of confidence.*